# Ffmpeg Video Transcode Faliure [swscaler @ 000000000168ee60]

Tags: ffmpeg

We are using [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) version N-85653-gb4330a0 and during Video transcode received below error message. Can you suggest how to fix this issues?

> C:\Users\svc_daltranscode>ffmpeg -version
>   ffmpeg version N-85653-gb4330a0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
>   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avi
>   synth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-l
>   ibcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
>   le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex
>    --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-li
>   bwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
>
> libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
>
> libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
>
> libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
>
> libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
>
> libavfilter     6. 87.100 /  6. 87.100
>
> libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
>
> libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
>
> libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100

---

> 2017-11-09 14:52:24,234 | INFO  | session=       | user=           | com.artesia.common.lang.ProcessUtils | Process completed with exit value 1
>
> 2017-11-09 14:52:24,234 | WARN  | session=       | user=           | com.artesia.server.video.transcode.FFMpegAsyncTranscoder | Running FFMPEG process exited with code:1
>
> 2017-11-09 14:52:24,234 | ERROR | session=       | user=           | com.artesia.server.video.transcode.FFMpegAsyncTranscoder | FFMPEG failed with error:
>   [swscaler @ 000000000168ee60] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   [libx264 @ 0000000000bc1420] height not divisible by 2 (640x749)
>   Error initializing output stream 1:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #1:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
>
> 2017-11-09 14:52:24,234 | INFO  | session=       | user=           | com.artesia.server.video.transcode.FFMpegAsyncTranscoder | Sending transcode error notfication event for the transcode job:PIz1510257135161fa4afaa6-f629-4816-957c-065b7773a9b7
>
> 2017-11-09 14:52:24,312 | INFO  | session=       | user=           | com.artesia.server.video.transcode.FFMpegAsyncTranscoder | Sending transcode complete notification for the job:PIz1510257135161fa4afaa6-f629-4816-957c-065b7773a9b7

Thanks,
Naveen